# How to manage to take latitude and longitude of my android phone in cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

Pls help! How to manage to take latitude and longitude of my phone from the "#btn_2" click? 
for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="Ready()">
    <div class=".app">
        <form style="padding: 15px" id="form_1" name="form_1">
            <br>
            <button type="Submit" id="btn_2">geo location</button>
        </form>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

for index.js:

```
function Ready(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_2').click(function(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { 
timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    });
});
}
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

when try to click the button in my phone, it does not show any alert, neither success nor error alert. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press your button it submits your form "form_1" and probably page is reloaded. That can be a reason. Try to move the button out of the form, or add another without type="submit".

In the first time when you try to check geolocation you can be askd about permissions. Check if you didn't deny it my mistake.

Also you can try to reinstall the geolocation plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Here is my working code

```
<div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            <button id="geo-button" class="button">Geo</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

    const geoButton = document.getElementById('geo-button');

    geoButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
              'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
              'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
              'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
              'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
        }, function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        });
    });
}}
```

Also don't forget to add it for iOS

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```